# Realloc failing after second call

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I'm attempting to read in a list of words to be sorted and I start out with a fairly small array (10 elements) and then would like to increase the size of the array by 10 if the current capacity isn't enough. This seems to work with the first realloc, but I get a SIGABRT when trying to call realloc again. I'm sure it is a simple thing I'm not seeing, but I can't seem to figure it out. Here is my program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *string = malloc(100);
    // Array of pointers starting with 100 elements
    char **toSort = malloc(100*sizeof(char *));
    if(toSort == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        // Each string can be up to 100 characters long
        toSort[i] = malloc(101);
        if(toSort[i] == NULL) {
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    // Get all lines in the file
    int counter = 0;
    int max = 10;
    char *toAdd;


    FILE *txt = fopen("wlist0.txt", "r");


    while(fgets ( string, 100, txt ) && counter < max) {;

        toAdd = malloc(100);
        if(toAdd == NULL) {
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy(toAdd, string);

        toSort[counter] = string;
        counter++;

         //if the array needs to be enlarged
        if(counter == max) {
            char **new = realloc(toSort, (max+10) * sizeof(char));
            if(new == NULL) {
                exit(1);
            }
            for(int i = max; i < max + 10; i++) {
                toSort[i] = malloc(101);
                if(toSort[i] == NULL) {
                    exit(1);
                }
            }
            toSort = new;
            max += 10;
        }
    };

    for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        char *word = toSort[i];
        printf("%s", word);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
       free(toSort[i]);
    }

    free(toSort);


    return 0;
};
```

Like my comments say, my strings have a maximum length of 100 characters. I suppose I could dynamically allocate memory for the strings as well, but I'll worry about that when I have the other realloc working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should use functions instead of putting everything in your `main()`. That would make your code way easier to read!

Comment: @purec Noted. I removed them.

Comment: @user3121023 Thanks! That seems to help. I figured it was something small.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! I've been working on this for so long now i forgot to sort it all out.

Comment: @purec: The C Standard mandates that it is valid to pass `NULL` to `free()`.

Comment: @alk: yes, I was wrong. But at least it makes no sense.

Comment: Yeah I'm chasing these down as I see them. Is it better to increment my array by one each time? I was under the impression that realloc was pretty demanding, but on the other hand not having unused memory is also a good idea.

Comment: It seems that you have some operations with toSort while it has same old size. Just move   toSort  = new;   before for loop.

Comment: @purec why? It doesn't hurt anybody to do `free(NULL)`, in fact this is one nice property of `free` when you are freeing arrays of dynamic allocated pointers.

Comment: @Pablo   if(!p) free(p)  (our case) doesn't make sense.

Comment: @purec he? I don't understand what you mean. Where exactly is the OP doing that?

Comment: Then what we are talking about?

Comment: @purec I'm talking about  (the now removed) comment of yours that said "don't free NULL pointers`, to which I responded with why not. alk also responded to the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code assigns values to `toSort` after it the memory it points to is freed/modified by `realloc()`:

```
     //if the array needs to be enlarged
    if(counter == max) {
        char **new = realloc(toSort, (max+10) * sizeof(char));
        if(new == NULL) {
            exit(1);
        }
        for(int i = max; i < max + 10; i++) {
            toSort[i] = malloc(101);  <--- toSort is invalid here
            if(toSort[i] == NULL) {
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        toSort = new;
        max += 10;
    }
```

This will work better:

```
     //if the array needs to be enlarged
    if(counter == max) {
        char **new = realloc(toSort, (max+10) * sizeof( *new )); <-- fixed here, too
        if(new == NULL) {
            exit(1);
        }
        toSort = new;
        for(int i = max; i < max + 10; i++) {
            toSort[i] = malloc(101);
            if(toSort[i] == NULL) {
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        max += 10;
    }
```

There may be other errors in your code.  I haven't fully examined it.

Comment: Thanks for that! I noticed the same thing and I was just in the process of changing it. This does work and I will mark it as accepted.